# def vs. define_method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm experimenting with Ruby and am confused by the following behavior. In a file `test.rb` I have the following code:

```
def my_method
  puts "Output of my_method"
end

define_method(:my_other_method) do
  puts "Output of my_other_method"
end

puts methods
```

I run this file from the command line using `ruby test.rb`, and the output is a list of methods:

```
to_s
inspect
my_other_method
nil?
===
=~
!~
eql?
hash
<=>
class
singleton_class
clone
dup
itself
taint
tainted?
untaint
untrust
untrusted?
trust
freeze
frozen?
methods
singleton_methods
protected_methods
private_methods
public_methods
instance_variables
instance_variable_get
instance_variable_set
instance_variable_defined?
remove_instance_variable
instance_of?
kind_of?
is_a?
tap
send
public_send
respond_to?
extend
display
method
public_method
singleton_method
define_singleton_method
object_id
to_enum
enum_for
==
equal?
!
!=
instance_eval
instance_exec
__send__
__id__
```

As you can see, `my_other_method` is in the list, but `my_method` is not. What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see, my_other_method is in the list, but my_method is not.
>   What causes this?

Ruby treats `defs` at the toplevel differently than `defs` inside a class: toplevel defs become private methods of the Object class. Yet:

> [Object#methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-methods):   Returns a list of the names of public and protected
>   methods...

```
def my_method
  puts "Output of my_method"
end

define_method(:my_other_method) do
  puts "Output of my_other_method"
end

print "public and protected:\n\t"
puts methods.grep(/my/)
print "private:\n\t"
puts private_methods.grep(/my/)

--output:--
public and protected:
    my_other_method
private:
    my_method
```

It's undocumented, but `define_method()` actually creates a `public` method:

```
print "public:\n\t"
puts public_methods.grep(/my/)

--output:--
public:
    my_other_method
```

And:

```
p Object.public_methods.grep(/my/)

--output:--
[:my_other_method]
```

Comment: I see. So `def` creates a private method? Is this just a special case because the code is in the `main` object? When defining a class, methods are defined with `def` and they are public unless specified otherwise.

Comment: *Is this just a special case because the code is in the main object*--Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `def` on the top level declares a method as a private method of the `Object` class, thus you don't see it in the list of public methods. But you still can call it directly anywhere on the top level and from inside of an object of any class.

Example:

```
def my_method
  puts "Output of my_method"
end

class Foo
  def use_my_method
    my_method # it can be called there
  end
end

Foo.new.use_my_method
my_method
```

Comment: `Method#owner `=> *Returns the class or module that defines the method* 1) `puts method(:puts).owner` => Kernel, 2) `puts method(:my_method).owner` => Object, 3) `p Kernel.private_methods.grep(/my/)` => [:my_method].  Ha!

Comment: Yes, it seems that global methods are actually defined as private `Object` methods, not the `Kernel` ones, not sure why I had thought that they are defined on the `Kernel`.

Comment: No, I think you are correct.  I think that is a result of how method() works.  I think owner() must just call self.class, and method() captures self='main'.  So, even if my_method gets added to Kernel, owner() reports self.class as Object.  I think that could be considered a bug.

Comment: But that doesn't explain how `method(:puts).owner` results in Kernel being output.  Ruby's confused, and I'm confused.  Calling `method(:puts)` is equivalent to `self.method(:puts)`, and at the toplevel that is equivalent to `main.method(:puts)`, and so `self=main`.  If `owner()` just calls self.class, then `method(:puts).owner` should output Object too.   I'll have to think about that some more.

Comment: Well, seems that everything defined on the top level goes to Object, while anything defined inside Kernel, goes to Kernel: `module Kernel; def foo; end; end; puts method(:foo).owner`, that returns `Kernel`.

Comment: Ah hah!  `p Kernel.private_methods(false).grep(/my/)` => [].  So the owner ***is*** actually Object, and Kernel inherits the method:  Module inherits from Object, and Kernel is an instance of Module.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be truthful.